# How to get all checked values in Ajax load checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have checkbox list that load by Ajax and I want to show the checked value in page while User checking each checkbox.

[image]

[image]

The team load by Ajax according to the parent selection. You can see at the above image that I want to get all checked value.

The problem now, it only can get the checked value in England. When I go to France and select Valenciennes, the previous checked will uncheck.
So how can I get the checked value from England and France?

I've used this jQuery below but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
var checkedc = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {//use map to create array of checked elements
    return this.value;
}).get().join(); //than join array with comma to string
$('#t').val(checkedc);
});
```

HTML to show the checked value

```
<input type="text" id="t"></div>
```

HTML checkbox from Ajax load

```
<li class="teamList">
        <input type="checkbox" name="club[]" class="checkbox" id="cl<?php echo $clubsFetchData['club_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $clubsFetchData['club_id']; ?>"/>

        <label for="cl<?php echo $clubsFetchData['club_id']; ?>"><img src="assets/img/clubs/<?php echo $clubsFetchData['club_image']; ?>"/>

        <div>
            <?php echo $clubsFetchData['club_name']; ?>
        </div>

        </label>
    </li>
```

Comment: add the checkbox as well or create a demo

Comment: Hi, please have a look at the checkbox code

Comment: i should work are you getting any error?

Comment: Please read my question carefully, I want to get all checked value based on Ajax load checkbox